# Becoming a dealer

Tags: probability, card-games

In a poker game with three players A, B and C, the dealer is chosen by the following procedure. In the order A, B, C, A, B, C, . . ., a card from a well-shuffled deck is dealt to each player until someone gets an ace. This first player receiving an ace gets to start the game as dealer. Do you think that everyone has an equal chance to become dealer?

Let $A_i$ be the event that the first ace appairs at $i$th attempt. Since $\mathbb{P}(A_k)=\frac{48}{52}\cdot \frac{47}{51}\cdot ... \cdot \frac{48-k+2}{52-k+2}\cdot \frac{4}{52-k+1}$ decreases for $k\rightarrow \infty$ and A starts the game before the others, the probability that A becomes a dealer would be greater than the probability for B and in turn the probability for B would be greater than the probability for C.

So defining $A=[$A becomes a dealer$]$ and $A_i=[$A become dealer at $i$th turn$]$, can I use $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}(A\cap A_i))=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_i)\mathbb{P}(A)$ to calculate them? If not, how can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A will be dealt a card only if $i$ is of the form $3k+1$.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha Let V and F the events "success" and "failure". So can I write $\mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_{i=0}^{?}(\frac{2}{3})^{3k}(\frac{1}{3})$? What is the apex of sum?

Comment: The probability of Ace appearing will keep going up after every card. As the denominator will keep going down but the numerator will remain $4$. What does that mean for $A$, $B$, $C$ based on the value of $i$?

Comment: @MathLover Sorry, I don't understand what you want to tell me.

Comment: The short answer is that no, this will be biased for $A$ to be a bit more likely since it is possible that multiple players receive an ace at what would have otherwise been the same turn.  How soon each player first receives an ace is not biased, however since "$A$ wins ties" this causes the bias.  You can fix this by making it an event which cannot be tied... for instance, the person who receives the Ace of Spades... Note however that $52$ is not a multiple of $3$ so to make it even chance, just remove a card different than ace of spades to make it a multiple of $3$.

Comment: My point is that everyone's chance of getting the first Ace will keep increasing as more cards are drawn. After $48$ cards are drawn, $A$ is a clear winner. $A's$ chance is better mainly due to the fact that he is starting.

Comment: But... why stop at just removing one card.  Remove all cards, having only Ace of spades and two other cards... and randomly give one card to each.  The player with ace of spades gets to be dealer.

Comment: @MathLover I tried again with more calm. We have $15$ possible turns in which no aces is drawn and $1$ turn (the final turn) in which it's certain that one ace is drawn. So we have $16$ turns of game. At the first turn, if no ace is drawn, we have $(\frac{48-k+2}{52-k+2})^3$. Thus, since the events $A \cap A_i$ are disjoint (if A becomes a dealer at the first turn is impossible that he becomes a dealer at the $i$th turns), we have $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{k=0}^{16}(A\cap A_i))=\sum_{k=0}^{16}\mathbb{P}(A\cap A_i)=\sum_{k=0}^{16}\frac{4}{52-k+1}(\frac{48-k+1}{52-k+2})^{3k}$. Right?

Comment: @MathLover If it is so, how can I solve that sum? Anyway I know that the solutions are $\mathbb{P}(A)=0,36$, $\mathbb{P}(B)=0,3328$ and $\mathbb{P}(C)=0,3072$.

Comment: Your summation is not correct. For example, $k=0$ should simply give $4/52$. Also, it can go from $k=0$ to $k=15$ ($16$ turns). I have tried to explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the probability will look for each turn -

Probability of A winning in 1st turn $P_A(1) = \dfrac{4}{52}$

Probability of nobody winning in 1st turn $Q(1) = \dfrac{48 \times 47 \times 46}{52 \times 51 \times 50} = \dfrac{48! \times 49!}{52! \times 45!}$

Probability of A winning in 2nd turn $P_A(2) = Q(1) \times \dfrac{4}{49} = 4 \times \dfrac{48! \times 48!}{52! \times 45!}$

Similarly, $Q(2) = \dfrac{48! \times 46!}{52! \times 42!} \,$ and $\, P_A(3) = 4 \times \dfrac{48! \times 45!}{52! \times 42!}$

So, $P_A(k+1) = 4 \times \dfrac{48! \times (51-3k)!}{52! \times (48-3k)!}$ where $0 \le k \le 15$

When I put this in **WolframAlpha**, I get $\, \sum \limits_{k=0}^{15} P_A(k+1) \approx 0.36$. See below from **WolframAlpha**.

[image]